# WebStorm special character encoding

Tags: html, webstorm, html-entities

Does WebStorm automatically convert special characters to HTML entities?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the [String Manipulation](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/2162) plugin. Then press <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>M</kbd> and select `Escape HTML`.

Answer (score 2):

**WebStorm 11**

1. Select the line that you want to "encode"

   ```
   <span>Special text: <, > or ' </span>
   ```
2. **Edit > Encode XML/HTML Special Characters**

   or

   press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> > type "Encode" > select **Encode XML/HTML Special Characters**

   [image]
3. The result looks like this:

   ```
   <span>Special text: &lt;, &gt; or &apos; </span>
   ```